# How to retrieve list of unique file name parts?

Tags: powershell

A folder with migration scripts has a mix of SQL and PHP files named like these:

```
2015-03-22.23-00.up.sql
2015-03-23.19-00.up.development.sql
2015-03-23.19-00.up.production.sql
2015-03-23.19-00.up.sql
2015-03-23.19-00.up.staging.sql
2015-03-27.14-00.up.php
```

I would like to get a list of all **unique** date/times parts of the files. The example folder should result in:

```
2015-03-22.23-00.up
2015-03-23.19-00.up
2015-03-27.14-00.up
```

Note: The up part might or might not be included.

I have come up with this code:

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.up.*' -File
$Files = $Files | Select BaseName -Unique | Sort-Object BaseName
foreach($File in $Files) {
    $RegEx = '(.*)\.up';
    $FileSchemaVersion = $File.BaseName -replace $RegEx,'$1'

    Write-Line $File
    # Do something
}
```

Unfortunately, it includes the development, production, staging in the list as well. So the actual result is:

```
2015-03-22.23-00.up
2015-03-23.19-00.up.development
2015-03-23.19-00.up.production
2015-03-23.19-00.up
2015-03-23.19-00.up.staging
2015-03-27.14-00.up
```

How to fix that?

I see two options:

1. (better) Remove whatever is after the date time part, alternatively after the `up`, in the base name (`2015-03-23.19-00.up.staging` becomes `2015-03-23.19-00`, alternatively `2015-03-23.19-00.up`) before checking for uniqueness and sorting. For this, I do not know how to efficiently inject the second line to make this happen.
2. (acceptable) Do not include the files with something after `up` in the `$Files` collection at all. For this, I have not found a way how to pass this conditon into the `-Filter` parameter on the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this meet your needs?

```
$Files | % {
    $_.Substring(0,16)
    } | Sort -Unique
```